# Defining boundaries of a hitbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been working on a simple brick breaker game in Javascript for the past few weeks and come across an issue with creating a hitbox that I have no clue on where to begin fixing it.

**A brief overview of what's going on**:
My Hitbox class takes in a gameObject (a ball, or a brick, etc; defined elsewhere) and in the constructor sets its own position, width and height as the given game object's respectively. It has 2 arrays that I use for collision detection, one for the left/right sides and one for the top/bottom. Lastly it has 4 objects (or in this case positions) that define the "side" of the hitbox. These objects contain a singular value and an array of values.

Since every hitbox is going to be some form of a rectangle, I can simplify the creation of a hitbox because both left/right sides are vertical lines (all x values will be the same) and both top/bottom are horizontal lines. (all y values will be the same)

For instance, starting with the **left side** of the hitbox:
I know the starting point will be the **top left corner** of the object **(gameObject.position.y)** and the ending point will be the **bottom left corner**. **(gameObject.position.y + gameObject.height)** So, all I need to do is loop through all the y values up to the ending point to create the left side of the hitbox. So, the positions of the left side of the hitbox would be:

```
(gameObject.position.x, sides[0])
(gameObject.position.x, sides[1])
(gameObject.position.x, sides[2])
...
(gameObject.position.x, sides[n])
```

And the same logic for the right side:

```
(gameObject.position.x + gameObject.width, sides[0])
(gameObject.position.x + gameObject.width, sides[1])
(gameObject.position.x + gameObject.width, sides[2])
...
(gameObject.position.x + gameObject.width, sides[n])
```

Here's the class itself. You can ignore the console.log() functions in the buildHitbox() member function; I was just using those for testing.

```
export default class Hitbox{
  constructor(gameObject){
    this.position = gameObject.position;
    this.width = gameObject.width;
    this.height = gameObject.height;
    this.sides = [];
    this.tops = [];

    this.leftSide = {
      x: gameObject.position.x,
      y: this.sides
    };

    this.rightSide = {
      x: gameObject.position.x + gameObject.width,
      y: this.sides
    };

    this.topSide = {
      x: this.tops,
      y: gameObject.position.y
    };

    this.bottomSide = {
      x: this.tops,
      y: gameObject.position.y + gameObject.height
    };
  }

  buildHitbox(){
    // left/right sides of hitbox
    for(var sideIndex = this.position.y; sideIndex < this.height; sideIndex++){
      this.sides.push(sideIndex);
    }
    //console.log("hitbox left side: ", this.leftSide);       //SUCCESSFULL
    //console.log("hitbox right side: ", this.rightSide);      //SUCCESSFULL

    // top/bottom sides of hitbox
    for(var topIndex = this.position.x; topIndex < this.width; topIndex++){
      this.tops.push(topIndex);
    }
    //works for far left brick but not  far right
    //console.log("hitbox tops sides: ", this.topSide);
    //console.log("hitbox bottom sides: ", this.bottomSide);
    //works for far left brick but not for right 
}
```

**Here's my issue**

The test case I'm using for this is a brick at the top left corner of the canvas and at the top right corner of the canvas. The canvas itself is 1000px x 600px, so the left brick will start at position (0,0) and the right brick will start at (950,0) because each bricks' width is 50px.
The left and right sides of the hitbox are working correctly, (seen below)
[values of left/right side arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGQ7p.jpg)
but when I apply the same logic to the top and bottom array, it works as intended for the left brick but doesn't populate the array for the right brick.
[top/bottom values showing empty arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCmpQ.jpg)

I have already checked to make sure that the right brick shows it's starting x position as 950, and it does so I know it's not an issue with my level generator.
Maybe it has something to do with the bounds of the canvas?
Maybe it has something to do with the IDE I'm using? (codesandbox.io)
Maybe it has something to do with how things are rendered in javascript?
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated and I am willing to share more aspects of the game if needed. I am just completely stuck at the moment and can't really progress until I figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not anything else but the code bug.

You should use `topIndex < this.position.x + this.width` instead of `topIndex < this.width`.

The right code block is here:

```js
    for(var sideIndex = this.position.y; sideIndex < this.position.y + this.height; sideIndex++){
      this.sides.push(sideIndex);
    }
    console.log("hitbox left side: ", this.leftSide);       //SUCCESSFULL
    console.log("hitbox right side: ", this.rightSide);      //SUCCESSFULL

    // top/bottom sides of hitbox
    for(var topIndex = this.position.x; topIndex < this.position.x + this.width; topIndex++){
      this.tops.push(topIndex);
    }
    //works for far left brick but not  far right
    console.log("hitbox tops sides: ", this.topSide);
    console.log("hitbox bottom sides: ", this.bottomSide);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!! It's simple mistakes like these that make me question how I ever graduated college! lol

Comment: @bumblebee Copy it into chrome devtool console and add a break point to the line of `this.tops.push(topIndex)`,  you will find it never stop, so there must be  something wrong with the condition of the loop, that is my way to find out the bug. Hope this help.